# How to get all primary sort keys from table with composite keys in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'd like a list of all the primary sort keys from a table with a composite primary key (partition key and sort key). The table contains many partitions.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answer mentions, Scan() would be your only solution over the table itself...

This would not be fast or cheap on a large table.

If you need this regularly, consider a couple other options:

1. using a trigger (Dynamo streams + lambda) to track key values on insert
2. a Global secondary index with a dummy hash key value, and sort key of the actual keys

Comment: Definitely use streams if you need access to this data as it changes. The GSI option isn't a bad idea if the data changes infrequently. It can reduce the cost of reading the data because the GSI would only include the keys (and the dummy value). But the cost of writing the data goes up, at least for the initial record, and writes are a lot more expensive. So keep that in mind if going that route.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the `scan`, sort the result and remove the duplicates.

It would be wise to also use the `ProjectionExpression` property of the `scan` to limit the response to only the partition and sort keys.